# Where is Orchard Widget Data stored?

Tags: database, orchardcms

I am trying to find saved widget data in the DB for an Orchard CMS site that I have taken on the maintenance for.

The Orchard_Framework_ContentItemRecord table for the relevant Widget ID just has a  tag as the content and not the actual content.

I can't seem to find where the actual data is stored.

(Orchard v.1.5.1.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it eventually in Common_BodyPartRecord